# Gnat problem with a rotating composter

Tags: composting, pest-management

I use a Maze Compost Tumbler, which is a 2-sided rotary composter, to compost kitchen scraps.  By volume, I add equal parts kitchen scraps, sawdust and peat moss whenever I add the scraps.  It is rotated twice a day.

The lids on this composter are kept shut. It has vent ports which I keep closed.  It is in a re-purposed stock trailer so it gets some sunlight, but not a large amount of it.  However, I cannot put it outside the trailer because bears would break into it to eat the scraps.

The problem I am having with it is that it has become a breeding spot for Gnats.  The compost is used in a vegetable garden, so I am not willing to use poisons to kill them.   We placed a fan on it to blow the the gnats away, but if there is any decline in the population of gnats because of the fan, it is negligible.

Does anyone know a non-poisonous way to rid it of gnats?

Comment: google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=XOa&ei=ASqWX-a5Derv9APi1oz4CA&q=compost+flies+solution

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! How often do you turn your compost? And do you bury your scraps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnat's are attracted to fruit, if that's what you're putting in the bin, you've identified the problem. One way is to Freeze your fruit/vegetable scraps in the freezer, this eliminates their odor, then shred em in a blender/food processsor. Mix it deep in the pile so bugs cant get at it.

Comment: Yes, I am putting fruit skins/scraps into the pile.   Starting the freezing process now.  Thank you.

Comment: LazyReader's observation about gnats being attracted by fruit proved true.   We discontinued adding fruit scraps to the bin and within a few days observed a dramatic reduction in the gnat problem.   We think once all the present gnat eggs have hatched, that the problem will be eliminated.